# second level cache in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, slf4j, ehcache, second-level-cache

Please help me to configure correctly the second level cache in Hibernate 5. I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Jcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ehcache 3.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I have the following exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory Why the LoggerFactory can not be find by ehcache? Is it kind of version conflict? Thank you

Comment: You have two questions here.  One is about second level cache and the other is a `ClassNotFoundException`.  It might be best to place these into separate questions.  For the second level cache question, I would recommend showing us a bit of your work so we can help you better.  For the 'ClassNotFoundException` I would recommend looking at how to setup Ehcache and Logging on the web.  There are a lot of examples out there that should help.

Comment: The problem is there are examples for earlier versions of Hibernate. For Hibernate 4 for example. I have read the official documentation and different examples and I could not find the answer. The problem is that cache provider requires loggerfactory and does not see it. I add full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I can not edit my question. The exception take place here: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.ehcache.impl.internal.spi.serialization.DefaultSerializationProvider.<clinit>(DefaultSerializationProvider.java:58)
 at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.createCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:147)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

Comment: Where are you deploying/running? Because this looks like a class loader issue. The dependencies are fine

Comment: I use Maven for package and Intellij Idea to run